# Lock order details page in backend when being viewed by another user

Tags: orders, backend, permissions, edit-order

Is it possible to restrict access to orders detail page when it is viewed by another user?

Comment: Does anyone know about a module with requested functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit user roles in System => Permissions => Roles => (select the role) => Role Resources.

Comment: I meant to make not be possible to edit order when another user is already editing it. Is that possible?

Comment: No! Actually it's not possible.